# "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable" in model.fit_generator

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am running on collab my notebook to train an Unet for image segmentation on Camvid dataset.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e7IMp-ho1xkeHgEjoXsd33cpXYRUjGSG/view?usp=sharing

This is the error:

[image]

Something wrong with model.fit_generator(). Can anyone have a look at the collab link and help me to fix this bug?

Comment: No access to your notebook

Comment: @dimay I have changed the link to editable. Please help me.

Comment: For some reason when I open the file, it comes up with a bunch of raw JSON data.

Comment: @Kettle3D Can you see Open with Colab button on the top of the file, under the address bar.

Comment: No. I see "Open with Text Editor" instead.

Comment: @Kettle3D I cloned from this. Could you please look at this at: https://github.com/advaitsave/Multiclass-Semantic-Segmentation-CamVid/blob/master/Multiclass%20Semantic%20Segmentation%20using%20U-Net.ipynb

Comment: I've had a look at it, but I don't have numpy so I can't run it.

Comment: @Kettle3D No kidding please.